# Можно ли как-то в Postgres при сортировке при помощи collation игнорирорвать emoji, чтобы они не попадали в сортировку?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Предположим у нас есть какой-то collation:

```
CREATE COLLATION my_collation (
    provider = icu,
    locale = '...'
);
```

Есть ли какой-то параметр позволящий игнорировать символы emoji? Не нашел ответа в документации, пробовал reorder=symbols

Comment: Вероятно, придётся создать собственную сортировку: [CREATE COLLATION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcollation.html) и правила для неё: [Rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#ICU-TAILORING-RULES)

Comment: Да, безусловно попробовтаь стоит, спасибо